# Perform 2 CGAffineTransform in a UIView.Animate - Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, swift3

Hey so i want a button in my view to grow when the view loads with a little animation.

When the view loads ect i set the start values

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let shrink = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0);
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -90)
    checkButton.alpha = 0
    nextView.transform = shrink.concatenating(rotate)

}
```

and then in view did appear I perform the animations

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
        let grow = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1);
        let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
        self.checkButton.alpha = 1
        self.nextView.transform = grow.concatenating(rotate)
    })
}
```

But only the grow animation works?
How do i get it so it grows from scale 0 to scale 1 and rotates from 90 degrees to 0 degrees?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why starting at scale 0 prevents it from rotating, but bumping up the scale on willAppear did the trick.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let shrink = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01);
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -90)
    checkButton.alpha = 0
    nextView.transform = shrink.concatenating(rotate)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
        let grow = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1);
        let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
        self.checkButton.alpha = 1
        self.nextView.transform = grow.concatenating(rotate)
    })
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:) uses radians, -90 might not be the value you are after